# C: Returning a string from function?

Tags: c, string, function, return

So I have this function that takes a value from 1-13 and returns a string.

```
const char *valueName(const int valueNum)
{
    switch (valueNum) {
    case 1: return  "Ace";
    case 2: return  "Two";
    case 3: return  "Three";
    case 4: return  "Four";
    case 5: return  "Five";
    case 6: return  "Six";
    case 7: return  "Seven";
    case 8: return  "Eight";
    case 9: return  "Nine";
    case 10: return  "Ten";
    case 11: return  "Jack";
    case 12: return  "Queen";
    case 13: return  "King";
    }

    return "(invalid suit)";
}
```

This function works with no issues, but my teacher says multiple return-statements is bad practice so I should instead use the switches to assign the string to a variable and return that. However I can't seem to figure out how to do that. Do I need to use pointers for this? 
According to my teacher this should be an easy fix but whatever I try it wont work.

Thanks in advance!

P.S Not asking for points or whatever but please dont downvote just because it's obvious to you; I'm still a beginner.

Comment: `multiple return-statements is bad practice` why don't you ask why?

Comment: *multiple return-statements is bad practice* Bollocks.  Your code is clear and concise.  Forcing changes to adhere to some blind rule about a single return statement makes the code *harder* to understand.

Comment: why return 'invalid suit' when the function doesn't otherwise mention suit?

Comment: You cannot (and do not) return a string (i.e. an array) in C or pas it to a function. Only pointers.

Comment: And your teacher is wrong. That is a matter of personal preference and actual code. Sometimes multiple returns can very much enhance code readability - if used consistently (which is good advice in general).

Comment: Not sure what the assignment text said, but in general it is better practice to return a _null pointer_ on failure. That can easily be checked by the caller.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Welcome in the world of Automotive - Praise MISRA,. our ruler. Like every religion you have to believe, not ask for reasons. (disclaimer: that was meant sarcastically! - I fully agree with you).

Comment: In theory, the flow of a program should be strictly determined by flow control structures (e.g. conditionals and loops). In practice, `goto`, `break`, `continue` and `return` serve a purpose. Your teacher is doing you a disservice by pretending otherwise.

Comment: Note: if valueNum is an enum value, may be consider use the X macro: http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-c-x-macros/184401387

Answer (score 8):

You can simply use an array of strings:

```
const char *valueName(int valueNum) {
  static const char * const names[] = { "(bad)", "Ace", "Two", ...};
  if (valueNum<1 || valueNum>13) valueNum=0;
  return names[valueNum];
}
```

If you really want to have a `const int` parameter, then:

```
const char *valueName(const int valueNum) {
  static const char * const names[] = { "(bad)", "Ace", "Two", ...};
  return names[(valueNum<1 || valueNum>13)? 0 : valueNum];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to implement the correct way, plus one. I'd like to see const char* names[] though.

Comment: This is good, and it's very smart to reuse zero for invalid value. You should avoid declaring `names` in local scope, because it never changes, so copying pointers onto stack is probably a waste. (that was a long way of saying "make `names` `const` and function-`static`.")

Comment: static const char, pretty please with sugar on top?

Comment: up to `static const char * const names`?

Comment: I always wonder what a `const int` argument is really good for. If the function is that long or complicated you loose oversight on any change, you have done something wrong already.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Yes, with const please!

Answer (score 5):

Looks good to me. (But to nitpick, note that you're not really returning a *string*, but a `const` pointer to the first element of a null-terminated read-only array of `char`s.)

It also is clear to read since you don't need `break` statements.

But some folk like to only have one `return` per function as that can help debugging. If you need to use a variable then use something like:

```
const char *valueName(const int valueNum)
{
    const char* foo;
    switch (valueNum) {
    case 1: 
        foo = "Ace";
        break;
    ...
    default:
        foo = "(invalid suit)";
        break;
    }
    return foo;
}
```

Note that the pointer will point to *read-only* memory. Don't attempt to modify its contents.

Moving on, you could use an *array* of character string literals, and return an element to that. But take care that any indexing is within the bounds of such an array:

```
const char *valueName(const int valueNum)
{
    static char* names[] = {"(invalid suit)", "Ace", ...};
    return names[(valueNum < 0 || valueNum > 13) ? 0 : valueNum];
}
```

Comment: Question: Are string literals written to a string table section of memory at the beginning of the program(even if the function is not called). is the address of string literal valid throughout the life of the program?

Comment: If the runtime asks for it, it must be there. I can't see why a compiler couldn't remove them if thy are not used.

Answer (score 1):

The function can be written simpler

```
const char * valueName( size_t valueNum )
{
    static const char *suit_names[] = 
    {
        "(invalid suit)", "Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", 
        "Seven",, "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"
    };

    const size_t N = sizeof( suit_names ) / sizeof( *suit_names );

    return valueNum < 1 || valueNum >= N ? suit_names[0] : suit_names[valueNum];
}
```

Comment: Why make the function static? Doesn't the suit_names[] just need to be static?

Comment: @Chimera It is a typo. I wanted to set the array as static.:)